# tableView didSelectRow not properly functioning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My other question was ambiguous so I will make this one clearer. I have a table view on one viewController and when a cell is selected, it saves a number to NSUserDefaults. On my main viewController, I retrieve this number and want to update a label with it. I did some debugging and found that when I go back to my main viewController from the tableView one, this is the order at what happens:

1) main view loads
2) tableView cell tap recognized
3) number saved to NSUserDefaults

How would I change the order so that the main view loads last so that when I click a cell, it changes the label in my main viewController?

Here is the code from my didSelectRow method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 NSString *pointsPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"totalPoints"];
 NSString *numberFirst = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"numberFirst"];

int totalPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: pointsPath];
int number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:numberFirst];

if([indexPath row] == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Selected First row");
    if(totalPoints < 10)
    {
        if (number != 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Did not add a point, but saved");
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:numberFirst];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        }
        else if (number == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"Added a Point");
            int newPoints = totalPoints + 1;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newPoints forKey: pointsPath];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:numberFirst];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            int logPoints = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:pointsPath];
            NSLog(@"Point Count:%i", logPoints);
        }


    }
```

Comment: A poor topic that implies that you have to examine the code to see the target development platform...

Comment: The target development platform is iOS...i'm not familiar with Mac dev but I'm not sure why it's important

Comment: What have you done to debug this???  The first thing to do is to see if the methods above are actually being called.  Next determine if the data you expect is showing up where you expect it.  (BTW, it's kinda stupid to write a file just to communicate a number from one VC to another.)

Comment: Where does `readNumber` come from??

Comment: (Why do you bother providing an `error` parameter if you never check it?)

Comment: Why do you use two different encoding types?

Comment: @aaronBrager thanks I didn't notice that.

Comment: @HotLicks I left out so much code out for a reason. There's no need to spam all this unnecessary code to everyone. I displayed what was important and I have used NSLog on all the methods and their conditionals and they all work fine it just doesn't update correctly

Comment: @rob sorry that was implied but I'll add it anyway.

Comment: Where are you creating the viewController instance? Are you even adding it to the view?

Comment: @V2Krazy  are you sure the viewwillappear is called?

Comment: It looks just like it does how I edited it

Comment: Your code works fine in my hands. Are you calling save: from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:? If so, you should post that code.

Comment: What do you mean by "append string"? I don't see anywhere in your code that you're appending a string.

Comment: @rdelmar it changes the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i finally found the problem if anyone has this problem... You need to make sure that when the user selects a cell, it is a push segue not a modal... This is so frustrating that is was so simple!!

Answer (score 0):

A controller's view is loaded on demand. So the thing that triggers `viewDidLoad` is somebody else performing `controller.view`. If you've already pushed the view controller into a container view or otherwise started to present it then that'll be the agent responsible.

`viewDidLoad`, and under iOS 5 and below `viewDidUnload`, are intended to give you the hooks you need if you want to create some part of the view programmatically.

If what you're doing is trying to account for a setting that may have been changed while the controller wasn't visible, you should probably use `viewWillAppear:`. That's the intended way to determine when you're about to transition from invisible to visible.

If you wanted a completely active link between the two things then you would set up the view controller that displays the number to listen for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` and to update views as necessary when that occurs.

Comment: It still does the same thing. Do I have to invoke something in my tableViewController? It still loads the main view controller before it updates the NSUserDefaults from the tableView

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:` then what's causing those to be triggered? Where does it happen in relation to your `...didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: The viewDidLoad is the initial view controller so it doesn't let me select a row without it stopping. I NSLogged when I clicked a row, when it saves the number, and when the view controller loads. The main view controller loads before all of the stuff saves so the label doesn't update